# Should users be able to enter data directly into a pivot table

Tags: users, tables, type, data

... or should I offer them a separate formular/window where the user can fill the data to the related person?

Its about entering marks/grades of pupils for a certain subject. So sliding to the wrong line could be bad or good for the one or other pupil...

A separate Window could help, but the productivity is smaller.

What do you think?

Comment: Beyond the user tasts, that depends a lot on the whole page / form layout. It would be better fi you provide e.g. sketches or screenshots.

Comment: An editable pivotgrid/-table is the same on a screenshot as in your mind, so a screenshot won`t help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hugely more efficient to input values directly into the table. Especially in such a case where the user can input values, row after row. Try visualizing e.g. Excel, where the user can jot down numbers and switch to next row with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. There's no edit window involved, either.

I very well can imagine a bunch of angry teachers if they have to open a separate input box for *each* value or even for each student instead focusing just the grades.

Comment: I checked another popular competition app using also the direct efficient way. I will stick to it too. :)