# Okay to enter data directly into small table or better to go to new screen?

Tags: tables, data-entry

My organisation is working with developers to make a new health information system (For mainly desktop users). At moment of delivering the DFS, they are asking for more $$$$ as they say the complexity is much higher than expected initially. To determine complexity they look at number of screens and fields.  From the beginning they told us we had to always jump to a new screen to enter data and never enter data directly in a table.    The compelexity would be reduced by 20% if we were able to enter directly in a table.  But they state "to modify directly the summary table without going through the editing screen would lead to degraded user experience : not in accordance with the rest of the application + not recommended by UX designers"
The tables in question are simple with only 5-6 fields to fill per line (see below).  No one in our staff is knowledgeable in UX and so the higher ups are ready to yield to the developers and handover the money.  However in my experience as a user I think it would be much easier to fill in a table directly than have to click, enter a new screen, enter fields, save and then return to table and do the same for the 35 other lines.  Are we being taken for a ride?

[image]

Comment: We don't know anything about your developers and your application, so we can't answer about the implementation. However, I believe you're right on the UX part, check this other Q https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/should-users-be-able-to-enter-data-directly-into-a-pivot-table?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should users be able to enter data directly into a pivot table](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/should-users-be-able-to-enter-data-directly-into-a-pivot-table)

Comment: If you are unsure you can ask them regarding the argumentation for the decision. Just a 'recommendation from the UX expert' is not enough in my opinion, ask them why! Perhaps they did user tests for your application that showed that for your users this is the best solution. In general though,

Comment: *In general though I would say editing in the table directly is better

Answer (score 0):

In any interface there's a tension between making it instantly comprehensible for new users vs. fast and easy for heavy users.

They're taking a perfectly valid new-user/public-interface idea and applying it badly to an internal repeat-user situation. Someone read the books but doesn't understand them yet. Or needs the money.